# Poisson processes: Joint probability in overlapping intervals

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Two teams, A and B, play a soccer match. The number of goals scored by Team A is modelled by a Poisson process $X_t$ with rate $\lambda = 0.03$ goals per minute. The number of goals scored by Team B is modelled by a Poisson process $Y_t$ with rate $\mu = 0.02$ goals per minute. The two processes are assumed to be independent of each other. Let $N(t)$ be the total number of goals in the match up to and including time t (measured in minutes). The soccer match itself is 90 minutes in length.

If a total of two goals were scored by team A in the first half of the the match (2-0), what is the joint probability that the first goal took place in the first 15 minutes and the second goal was scored prior to minute 30?

I am unsure how to calculate this probability since the intervals (0, 15] and (0, 30] are not disjoint. Should I assume that the second goal took place between the 15th and 30th minute of the match? I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: The processes are assumed independent.  Where, in the definition of independence, would any assumption about time intervals appear?

Comment: Hint: The joint event whose probability you seek can be partitioned into two independent events whose probabilities can be calculated separately. Either A scored two goals in $(0,15]$ and none in $(15,30]$ or A scored one goal in $(0,15]$ and one goal in $(15,30]$. Since the score is $2$-$0$ at the end of 30 minutes of play, don't forget to include the probability that $B$ did not score a goal during these 30 minutes.